# Different statements of the Feynman-Kac formula

Tags: stochastic-analysis

In many books on finance, the PDE solved by Feynman-Kac is often formulated by the following:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x)+\mathcal{L}u(t,x)&=V(t,x)u(t,x),\\
u(0,x)&=\varphi(x)
\end{aligned}$$
where the generator is defined as $\mathcal{L}:=\mu(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$, $\varphi$ and $V$ continuous, $V\geqslant0$.
(One-dimensional case, cf. [this wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) and e.g. Definition 2.46 of *Interest-Rate Management*, R. Zagst.) Then the solution to this boundary problem (if exists) can be expressed as
$$u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\Big[\varphi(X_t)\exp\Big(-\int_0^tV(t,X_s)ds\Big)|X_t=x\Big],$$
where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the equivalent martingale measure, that is, the process $(X_t)$ is a martingale under $\mathbb{Q}$.

However, in other books (actually the lectures I have taken, or cf. [this wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_term_structure_model)) it is formulated as:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x)&=\mathcal{L}u(t,x)-V(t,x)u(t,x),\\
u(0,x)&=\varphi(x)
\end{aligned}$$
with the same functions and the same solution. The derivative on $t$ of $u$ stands on different sides of the equation...

**My Question:** Are these two formulations equivalent? How can we prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment: What you quote from your first wikipedia site is wrong. The solution (used in the finance literature) is
$$
u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}\Big[\varphi(X_T)\exp\Big(-\int_t^TV(s,X_s)ds\Big)|X_t=x\Big].
$$
Because $t$ is now the *lower* integration limit it flips the sign of the partial time derivative thus making this solution consistent with the other one.

Comment: oh...indeed! I didn't notice that they used different integration limits. Thank you!